# How to add Tinymce 6 add php code in textarea?

Tags: php, tinymce

how to add a php code in the editor textarea in tinyMCE 6 ?

Example :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCM5x.jpg
I need to execute php code in the editor block (page builder dev).

(my old textarea without tinyMCE working and execute php, tinyMCE not execute and delete the php code in textarea after save)

Thanks for help !
Dear Florian

Answer (score 0):

you can use the protect attribute of the TinyMCE configuration:

`protect: [ /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g // Protect php code ],`

**or** :

Use placeholders in your text, like this :

```
<h1 class="">__PHPCODE__<h1>
```

Then before the text is sent to database, replace the placeholders with the variables you want :

```
$yourtext = strtr($yourtext, ['__PHPCODE__' => $title]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks to reply, so i have this :
        protect: [
            /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g, // Protect php code
            /<\?=[\s\S]*?\?>/g // Protect php code
        ],

in my BDD MYSQL it saved this : <!--mce:protected %3C%3F%3D%20%24title%3B%20%3F%3E-->

Comment: You might have better luck creating your own templating style. Use a placeholder in the text, then when you're sending the data, search for that placeholder and replace it.